# Image Intervention Image on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, image-manipulation, image-upload

So i got this error

```
Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\finfo_buffer()
```

I got this error when using Intervention image on my laravel so here is my code

```
    if(Input::hasFile('imgchick'))
    {
    $img = Image::make('images/chickens/1419125359-chicken.jpg'); //got the error on this part
    $file = ImageInput::file('imgchick');
    $name = time().'-'.'chicken.jpg';
    $file = $file->move(public_path() . '/images/chickens', $name);
    $farm->img_loc=$name;
```

I already updated my php.ini and uncommented the some codes that was said need on some of my research, but its still not working. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable [the `finfo_buffer` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php).

See here for more details:

https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/131